# Wagtail-Localize translated home page not connected to site

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

So the problem is simple:
Translated home page is not connected to any site. Everything is working kind of properly, I can open translated pages manually like this: `/en/...`. But for example there is no `LIVE` button on the translated page, to which i'm used to.

[image]
This is the main home page, my site defaults to.

[image]
And this is translated home page.

[image]
Also in the explorer, it shows a warning that this page is not connected to any site, which I think should not be.

[image]
Here in the red boxes it was written in what language each page is.

This is not a very big deal, but it's a little bit annoying and I'm planning to release this site in production soon, so editors may not understand which page to edit. **How can I fix this?** Maybe there is a way to change something in the database, so translated home pages are properly connected to the main home page?

I tried to delete database and remigrate everyting(which by the way gave me [this](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/6557) error, I fixed it by adding `locale_id=1` to the migration), nothing worked. I think this happened when I changed `LANGUAGE_CODE` from `en-us` to `ru-ru`, I'm not sure, but deleting and remigrating database should have fixed it but it didn't. :(

Somebody with 1500 reputation please create a `wagtail-localize` tag xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, posted a question, answer came up... Nevermind, I think many people will find this Q&A useful.

So the problem was in `wagtail_localize.locales` app, I changed it to `wagtail.locales` and everything is working now, I thought these apps are basically the same thing, but I was wrong.

**`.url` function on pages was not working too because of this issue.** Just replace the app!

Hope this helps! :P

Answer (score 0):

You need define the abbreviation of language in `IETF_language` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag
For example:

```
WAGTAIL_CONTENT_LANGUAGES = LANGUAGES = [
    ('vn', "Tiếng Việt"), #wrong
    ('vi', "Tiếng Việt Chuẩn"), #right
    ('en', "English"),
]
```